# Функция _getch() возвращает один и тот же код

Tags: c++, клавиатура

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            int code = _getch();
            std::cout << code << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

При нажатии любых стрелок на клавиатуре выводит код 224. Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следует читать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-160):

> The _getch and _getwch functions read a single character from the console without echoing the character. None of these functions can be used to read CTRL+C. When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code.

Соответственно для определения нажатия стрелок следует читать 2 раза:

```
auto const code{::_getch()};
auto const arrow_pressed{0xE0 == code};
if (arrow_pressed)
{
    auto const arrow_code{::_getch()};
    ::std::cout << arrow_code << ::std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 77
#define KEY_RIGHT 75

using namespace std;

void control() {
    switch (_getch()) {
    case KEY_UP:
        cout << KEY_UP;
        break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
        cout << KEY_DOWN;
        break;
    case KEY_LEFT:
        cout << KEY_LEFT;
        break;
    case KEY_RIGHT:
        cout << KEY_RIGHT;
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        control();
        /*if (_kbhit())
        {
            int code = _getch();
            cout << code << endl;
            break;
        }*/
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```